# Error when Publishing to Amazon Web Services from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to deploy directly to AWS from visual studio, this errors occurs:

```
    ...building deployment package 'C:\Users\Leon\AppData\Local\Temp\AWSDeploymentArchive_*****_v20190509101556.zip'

    ...invoking 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:manifest="C:\Users\Leon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2223.tmp" (...)

    ...error, package 'C:\Users\Leon\AppData\Local\Temp\AWSDeploymentArchive_*****_v20190509101556.zip' could not be found

    ...build fail, unable to find expected deployment package.
    ...build of project archive failed, abandoning deployment
```

I have tried to manually create the folder, It builds the package, but the result is a empty folder.